# суть асинхронности qt

Tags: qt, event-loop

здравствуйте, пытаюсь понять суть асинхронности в qt...
говорят, что qt - асинхронное программирование. вот, допустим, такой код:

```
void requests() {
     websocket->sendTextMessage(text1);

     websocket->sendTextMessage(text2);
}
```

мы посылаем запрос, приходит ответ, он ставится в очередь, далее посылаем второй запрос, ответ на него тоже ставится в очередь за первым ответом, и потом в слоте onTextMessageReceived мы обрабатываем поочередно ответы... притом, что на второе сообщение ответ может прийти раньше и, соответственно, обработан он будет раньше. не могу понять почему это асинхронный подход? параллельно ничего не обрабатывается, а мы заходим в слот onTextMessageReceived() только по выходу из функции requests(), т.е. фактически, синхронно после окончания функции requests()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы путаете асинхронность с параллельностью. Это два принципиально разных понятия.

Асинхронность - это способ не тратить время на ожидание в случае если время между запросом и ответом нам не известно (либо очень велико), и есть возможность в этой паузе выполнить какие-то другие действия, а обработку ответа отсрочить до окончания этих действий, если ответ придет раньше. При этом действия выполняются не параллельно, а последовательно, но сама очередность определяется не программой, а внешними задержками.

Если бы вы синхронизировали ваши запросы, то последовательность была бы такой:

1. Отправить запрос 1
2. Ждать ответа на запрос 1 или истечения таймаута
3. Обработать ответ на запрос 1 или ошибку истечения таймаута
4. Отправить запрос 2
5. Ждать ответа на запрос 2 или истечения таймаута
6. Обработать ответ на запрос 2 или ошибку истечения таймаута

В приведенном же вами примере между первым запросом и обработкой ответа на него ваша программа делаете второй запрос, и, возможно, обрабатывает ответ на второй запрос.

Данный подход (асинхронный) удобен тем, что может быть выполнен на любом вычислительном устройстве, в отличии от параллельного, для которого нужна поддержка и со стороны процессора и операционной системы.

К тому же расход ресурсов на подготовку реально параллельного выполнения могут быть выше чем потери при асинхронном выполнении.

PS событийно-ориентированный подход - это один из способов реализации асинхронности, на мой взгляд, самый простой и понятный.

Comment: событийно-ориентированное программирование, в частности, для сети обычно считается(если я не ошибаюсь) что-то основанное на select/poll или еpoll(для линукса)... я так понимаю, в основе qt лежит тот же принцип, только как-то странно это происходит: мы с таким же успехом в конце функции requests могли просто вызвать обработчики без всякого qt-шного event-loop и механизма слотов... зачем тогда event-loop нужен в qt?

Comment: В `Qt` событийно-ориентированный подход лежит в рамках одного процесса. А epool/kqueue - это механизмы, обеспечивающие межпроцессное взаимодействие на основе событий, которое обеспечивает ОС. Понятия близкие, но ниша разная.

Comment: @xperious, сразу после запроса вызвать обработчики ответа? А откуда они возьмутся, если их нам должны прислать по сети? Вам пришлось бы писать цикл: если пришел ответ, то обработать, если нет - подождать и повторить. Собственно этот цикл за вас и реализует Qt. Но в нем проверяется наступление всех событий, на которые вы "подписаны"

Answer (score 2):

Нет такого понятия - асинхронное программирование. Асинхронным может быть исполнение. Если говорить про `Qt`, правильнее было бы сказать "событийно-ориентированное программирование". Суть которого заключается в обработке сигналов слотами.

Вы хотите асинхронной обработки сокетами данных? Так предоставьте этим сокетам такую возможность - вынесите их из основной нити исполнения, создайте пул нитей, где на одну нить будет один сокет. В таком случае будет независимая параллельная обработка сигналов каждого сокета. А это, сиречь, и есть желанная асинхронность.

Comment: не путайте асинхронность с параллельностью

Comment: Не путайте что я путаю) Параллельное исполнение без синхронизации - один из способов достижения асинхронности. Со своими плюсами и минусами.

Comment: Один из, но не единственный. Вопрос про случай отсутствия параллельности

Comment: Ну так я и написал так) ТС спросил "...параллельно ничего не обрабатывается..". Я ему посоветовал добавить немножко параллельности для обработки))) Наличие нескольких сокетов в одном треде гаратнирует только асинхронность+пареллельность I/O, но в один момент времени может работать только один обрабатывающий слот. Если скорость обработки пренебрежительно мала - подход хорош. А вот если наоборот (скорость I/O пренебрежительно мала) - распараллелить сам доктор прописал. Вот об этом и был мой сказ.